# Using HomeBrew to install MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, homebrew

I have MySQL `stable 8.0.19 (bottled)` installed via mac HomeBrew:

```
brew install mysql
```

and it asks me to follow these instructions in the **Caveat** section:

```
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
```

and when I run the `mysql_secure_installation` command with or without `sudo` I get:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
```

Now I tried looking for the default password. The MySQL installation process for macOS [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160820165556/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/osx-installation-pkg.html) shows that on the last step a temporary password is provided for the user:

```
   [][5]  
(source: [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-osx-excerpt/5.7/en/images/mac-installer-root-password.png))
```

However, I do not see any information about a temporary password within the HomeBrew terminal outputs. From here I tried:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

but I get:

> grep: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory

then I tried looking for that log file:

```
sudo find / -name mysqld.log
```

but I get lots of `find: ... Operation not permitted` instead of any meaningfull results.

I would appreciate if you could help me know

- if I have done everything correctly so far,

  - if not what mistakes I have made and how to fix them
- if yes how I can acquire the temporary password
- what are the next steps

Ideally, I should be able to follow the rest of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=418&v=2bW3HuaAUcY&feature=youtu.be) within the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I had some progress. I ran

```
brew services list
```

and it showed that `mysql stopped`, now I ran:

```
brew services start mysql
```

now the `mysql_secure_installation` script ran smoothly with

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.
```

helping me set up a password and other settings. Now you may install the MySQL Workbench (the GUI seen in [the tutorial](https://youtu.be/2bW3HuaAUcY?t=417)) by:

```
brew cask install mysqlworkbench
```

and you should be able to find and run MYSQLWorkbench from your `/Applications/` folder!

**P.S.** Wrote simple instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/b351fe7686de19a4c91d3e0b4c91080a).

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users, there is DBngin (https://dbngin.com) that gives
you push-button start/stop for MySql, PostgreSQL (and redis) .. different
versions with non-overlapping config/data directories.
Really saves me - and my students! - in my DB course.

Comment: Is this Free, Libre, Or Open Source Software (FLOSS)?