# How to run a script against a .sql database on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Sorry for me being a novice, I know this looks like a dumb question. I'm trying to follow [this](https://youtu.be/2bW3HuaAUcY) very beginner's tutorial. It seems the instructor is using the `employees.sql` database from [this sample database](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db). If I just run the command:

```
select * from employees;
```

I get the error

> Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.

I tried opening the `employees.sql` on the side:

but then running it returns the error message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source load_departments.dump' at line 1

And [this similar issue](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/issues/5) on their GitHub repository also doesn't help much. I tried following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/blob/master/README.md) on the sample database repository:

```
mysql < employees.sql
```

however, I get another error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foobar'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what are the prerequisites in the step by step form to be able to follow [the rest of this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2bW3HuaAUcY?t=435).

**P.S.** I'm on macOS Catalina and my Workbench version is 8.0, and MySQL

> mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.15 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/b351fe7686de19a4c91d3e0b4c91080a).

Comment: Your user error indicated you're logged in on a user that doesn't have the required privileges mentioned on the page you linked. I just tried it with a MySQL server installed on my pc and through Workbench on user root and it worked. Aside from a built-in error the employees.sql seems to have when trying to import departments dump, everything works fine.

Comment: @t1f I just installed MySQL and MySQL Workbench following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60865263/4999991). I followed the `mysql_secure_installation` steps to set a password for the `root` user and then used the password in Workbench. Any step by step instruction about how should I change that so I have the previlages?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Leonardo macOS. Sorry I did not think that would be relevant.

Comment: Can you log in your mysql root account typing in terminal: mysql -u root -p ?

Comment: @Leonardo yes. I just did and I am on `mysql>`. What should I do next?

Comment: @Foad since you're a new user I'd advise against using the command line. Sure, it's nice to learn, but..you have time for that :) use the Workbench GUI for now, it's easier and more intuitive.

Comment: I've asked only to now if the have the rights to access the system.

Comment: @t1f I would actually love to learn the command line tool next. so if there any solutions from that side it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Foad As you should, it's always good to learn to get 'dirty' too, not being reliant on GUIs and such, I was simply stating that for this circumstance, it would potentially make it more difficult to understand since you're already having problems with the GUI. Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/ and then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html and then https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line and so forth. Lots of resources available, do some google searches for `mysql command line`

Comment: @t1f thanks a lot. Sure it makes sense that I first figure the GUI out and then move to the more advances command-line interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in that repository.

You'll have to fix that.

Open up the `employees.sql` with an editor, like `Notepad++` for example then go to the bottom of the file where you will find this:

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

Try replacing:

```
"SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;"
```

with

```
"SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source C:/load_departments.dump ;
```

- Where `C:/` should be the actual path to the file in question, on your computer.
- Do this for every line in the file there at the end, adding the appropriate path.

Now import `employees.sql` and run it and see if it works.

### If it doesn't, then try doing it this way:

Delete **only** the following code and save the changes to the file.

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;
```

Now continue doing this:

- Open `Workbench`
- Add a new `MySQL connection` to your local `MySQL server`.

*Make sure you are connecting/adding the root user or another user that has the following privileges, to the connection:*

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, 
CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, REFERENCES, 
INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, 
LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW
```

- Double click and open your newly formed connection
- Go to **Left-Upper corner**, click on `File` then click on `Open SQL Script` and select the `employees.sql` from the repository you downloaded and click the **lightning icon**.

After that:

- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_employees.dump` then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_departments.dump`then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_dept_emp.dump`then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_dept_manager.dump`then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_titles.dump` then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_salaries1.dump`then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_salaries2.dump`then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.
- use the `Open SQL Script` again and open `load_salaries3.dump` then click the `Lightning icon` again in the newly opened file.

Now you're done importing the database.
You can now do your `select * from employees` query.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. How can I configure those privileges? [This](https://i.imgur.com/hHtaSZr.png) is what I see when I open the Workbench

Comment: Give it a connection name. Click on `store in keychain` next to password and add the password (not sure if it's different, I'm on Windows and it says `in vault` for me, not `in keychain`) then click `Test connection` in the lower right - if everything works fine click Ok then double-tap the newly formed connection in your `workbench` window. If everything is fine and you logged in, further follow the instruction in my answer above.

Comment: The `Test Connection` result is [this](https://i.imgur.com/WISzSCL.png) so I think I can follow the rest of the steps, I suppose.

Comment: @Foad Yup seems fine so far. Follow further and see how it goes.

Comment: then where do you write and run the `select * from employees;` line? I wrote it on the document opened in the `Query 1` tab but running it brings no results as expected from [the tutorial](https://youtu.be/2bW3HuaAUcY?t=485).

Comment: `Query1` is an already opened query that contains the sql script you previously imported. You can empty that (ctrl+a and delete everything) and write `select * from employees` or open another Query instance (menu - the first Icon that says SQL and has a + beneath it) and write in that empty, new one that pops up. Then you click the Lighting icon again to run what you wrote in the Query.

Comment: @Foad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_umYKqKaF0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKwR9fWsZJ4 and https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-mysql-workbench.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210377/discussion-between-t1f-and-foad).

Comment: @Foad I've edited my answer to include first fixing the error the repository contains and then running everything. It should work fine now. Please see the newly edited answer and adjust accordingly. Once you're done, if it has solved it for you, then consider accepting the answer so it can be used in the future for other potential visitors as the correct solution for your question. You can also join me in the chat fi you have more questions so as to not have lenghty discussions here in the comments. Click the continue this discussion in chat button above this comment if you'd like.

Comment: [Now](https://i.imgur.com/6h0PUlW.png) it runs with no errors, but still, the results are empty!

Comment: @Foad You seem to be missing the database. It's not seen in the left and the log middle down says 0 rows affected for everything. Start everything from the start - without the making a new connection part - use the one you previously created. It should work, I tested.

Comment: I think I have found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873722/4999991). I would appreciate it if you could check and let me know how do you think about that.

Comment: @Foad Seems alright, since it's official and on a quick look. Test it and see if you still get the loading error. My answer is precisely for that use case, if you get the error while loading the dumps, in which case, I edited and added another quick fix (you need to specify the path to the dumps right in the sql file). If the official approach, via cmd line works for you, by all means, use it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have found the solution, and it requires a little bit of command line. If you have followed [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/b351fe7686de19a4c91d3e0b4c91080a) to install MySQL and MySQL Workbench using HomeBrew, Then you should already have a user and a password set. Now assuming that you have downloaded [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db), The you need to go to the downloaded `test_db-master` and following the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html), from your terminal and run the command:

```
mysql -u <user_name> -p -t < employees.sql
```

where you replace the `<user_name>` with the user you want to use. In my case, it is just `root`. Then it asks for the user's password and you should see the database imported. Now lunch the MySQL workbench. And you should see the `employees` database in the `schemas` tab of the left-hand sidebar/panel. Now you need to double click on it, or right-click on it and select `set as default schema`:

alternatively, you could add

```
USE employees;
```

at the top of your script for the first time. Now you are good to go and can run the rest of the queries, following [the tutorial](https://youtu.be/2bW3HuaAUcY).